# 'IL/il.h' file not found, but it exists

Tags: macos, compilation, makefile, cegui

When trying to build cegui the above mentioned header file cannot be found, while it clearly exists in `/usr/local/include`. Why does this happen?

```
[ 29%] Built target CEGUIBase-0
[ 32%] Built target CEGUIOpenGLRenderer-0
[ 32%] Built target CEGUINullRenderer-0
[ 32%] Built target CEGUIExpatParser
[ 32%] Built target CEGUILibXMLParser
[ 32%] Building CXX object cegui/src/ImageCodecModules/DevIL/CMakeFiles/CEGUIDevILImageCodec.dir/ImageCodec.cpp.o
/Users/Adam/Downloads/cegui-0.8.3/cegui/src/ImageCodecModules/DevIL/ImageCodec.cpp:33:10: fatal error: 
      'IL/il.h' file not found
#include <IL/il.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you don't have `/usr/local/include` listed on your compile line.  Have you added `-I/usr/local/include` to your CFLAGS?  Or, because this output looks like it might be from a makefile using the cmake generator, have you added it via `include_directories`?  If it's a cmake generated makefile, you can run `make VERBOSE=1` to see the full compile line.